# Getting timestamp of each time pings enter and leave a radius

Tags: postgis

I have written code which gives the last time when a ping is recieved within a radius of a point using the max function (in a given time window).
However what I want is getting the timestamp of each time pings **enter or leave** the radius in the given time window, I can not figure out how to accomplish this.

```
with orig_dataset as (

select a.uc_id, cr.imei,cr.points_geom , lead(cr.points_geom) over (order by cr.created_at) as leading_points,cr.created_at as time_created
from campaign_routes cr 
left join assets a on a.imei = cr.imei

where cr.created_at between '2023-01-17 06:00:00 +05:00' and '2023-01-17 18:00:00 +05:00' 
and cr.imei in (select imei from assets a 

join asset_user_bindings aub 
on a.id = aub.asset_id 
where a.uc_id in (876,877,878,879,880) 
and
aub.user_type = 'team'
and 
aub.without_phone= 'false' 
and 
aub.inactive= 'false' 
)

 
)

,
cluster_groups as (
select uc_id_imported, uc_name_imported , id as cluster_id, points_geom as cluster_centroid  from team_support_centers tsc  
where uc_id_imported in (876,877,878,879,880)     )
,



dept_cluster_raw as (

SELECT 
       routes.uc_id ,
       cg.cluster_id ,
       cg.cluster_centroid ,
       routes.imei ,    
       routes.time_created::date as campaign_date,
       max(routes.time_created) as max_per_imei_cluster 
FROM cluster_groups as cg

CROSS JOIN LATERAL (

  SELECT routes.time_created,routes.imei, routes.uc_id
  
  FROM orig_dataset as routes
  
  where st_distance(
  st_transform(routes.points_geom, 4326)::geography ,
  st_transform(ST_SetSRID(cg.cluster_centroid, 4326),4326)::geography ) < 250
and 
(routes.time_created between '2023-01-17 06:00:00 +05:00' and '2023-01-17 11:00:00 +05:00'
)


  
) routes

group by 1,2,3,4,5

)
,

dept_master_data as 
(
select imei,uc_id,cluster_id,campaign_date, max_per_imei_cluster as individual_dept_time, avg(max_per_imei_cluster::time) over (partition by uc_id,cluster_id,campaign_date) as avg_dept_time
from dept_cluster_raw  
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably take your trace, add a column `in_radius` at `TRUE` if `< radius` and `FALSE` otherwise, then you detect crossing the radius with `in_radius != LAG(in_radius) OVER (PARTITION BY trace ORDER BY timestamp)`. For those points, if `in_radius = TRUE` then it means you enter, and otherwise you exit.

Other option: you create small segments between 2 consecutives points, and you detect intersection with the circle of your radius (created for exemple with `ST_Buffer`).